# Remove self-referencing information from release branch

Tags: git, merge, release

Assuming that release branches do not contain any content that you would not want to merge in others (e.g. workaround hacks for which proper fixes exist in later branch), is it possible to achieve clean merges between them?

In most projects, it is not possible because branches contain conflicting "administrative" content like:

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 4
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION =
NAME = Blurry Fish Butt
```

But version number is the most trivial and most often occurrence of this problem. There are often more.

Is it possible (and practical) to remove this "self referencing" information from the content?

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly a policy/administrative issue for each project. In essence, git doesn't care. It will track the files you tell it to track.

Some projects track this project metadata so that anyone can clone the project, build it, and get the same output. Other projects place that metadata outside of the files that git track, so that merging is easier, but you now have to keep track of that metadata elsewhere and make sure you use the correct one every time.